# Compare two data sets from different periods

Tags: compare, difference, identify, amortization

I want to compare two data sets (XLS) and easily identify differences. Each data set has the same structure: Loans information in rows and in columns the amount each loan amortizes in a calendar year (first Columns is loan ID and afterwards calendar years: 2023,2024,etc...). Each Dataset can have 1000+ rows. I have this dataset with info as of 2022 and as of 2023 and therefore I would like to identify the changes: New loans, Maturing loans, but probably the most interesting is the loan that changed the amortization profile.

Is there an efficient way to tackle this identification of changes job?

Appreciate any guidance

I've tried Excel, but it collapses as there are sometimes 10k rows ...